# For SQL Server 2012, how would I create a SQL report where one of the column names is changed to be the value of a data column from another table?

Tags: sql-server-2012

For SQL Server 2012, how would I create a SQL report where one of the column names is changed to be the value of a data column from another table?

For example these two tables.

**Person**

```
Location   FirstName   LastName   Menu01
```

**String**

```
Location   FieldName   Value
```

Sample data

Person

```
1 John Smith Yes
1 Mark Jones No
2 John James
```

String

```
1 Menu01 AgreeToTerms
2 Menu01 AddToMailingList
```

I would like to do a query

```
Select 
    FirstName, LastName, 
    (Location specific name from the String FieldName column) 
From 
    person
Where 
    Location = 1 
Order By 
    LastName
```

That returns

```
FirstName LastName  AgreeToTerms
---------------------------------
Mark      Jones     No
John      Smith     Yes
```

**Note**: this isn't a join question (but it may require a join or union?). All of the data comes from the `Person` table.

The one `Person` column `Menu01` needs to be renamed to be the data (`AgreeToTerms`) from the `Value` column of the `String` table.

Comment: Please tag the correct DBMS. mysql != mssql

Comment: This needs dynamic SQL. What exact query would you use to determine `Location specific name from the String FieldName column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL for this

Note the following:

- Use of `QUOTENAME` to escape the field name
- Checking of `sys.columns` that column name is correct
- `PRINT @sql` will show the whole command during testing, you can check it is correct
- If you have any data parameters to use, pass them through to `sp_executesql`, do *not* inject them

```sql
DECLARE @location int = 1;

DECLARE @fieldName sysname =
  (
    SELECT s.FieldName
    FROM String s
    JOIN sys.columns c ON c.name = s.FieldName AND c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('person')
    WHERE s.Location = @location
  );

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
Select 
    FirstName, LastName, 
    ' + QUOTENAME(@fieldName) + N'
From 
    person
Order By 
    LastName;
';

PRINT @sql; -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql;
```

Comment: It works and is the Perfect solution for what I am tryign to do.

Note: I only needed that column name as a column alias, not a real column name.

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
Select 
    Recordnumber, FirstName, LastName, 
    Menu01 AS ' + QUOTENAME(@fieldName) + N'
From 
    person
Where LocationId =   1210080
Order By 
    LastName;
';
Thank you!